# The violation of triangle inequality in KNN

Tags: machine-learning, k-nearest-neighbour, distance-functions

If the `0<p<1` in the [distance metrics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance), then the triangle inequality is violated.

[image]

The question as follows

Does the violation of this inequality affect the prediction of the KNN positively or negatively? and Why?

Comment: what do you mean by "distance metrics"? for $0<p\leq 1$ you still have $|x-y|^p\leq |x-z|^p + |z-y|^p$.

Comment: @jeza, your edit didn't help, since you just linked to a long Wikipedia page about distances in general. But probably you mean the [Minkowski distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_distance) $L_p$ for $p \in (0, 1)$?

Comment: In any case, "does this help or hurt" is probably unanswerable. Like any such question, the answer is going to be "it depends on the problem."

Comment: It's for $p < 1$, not $p \leq 1$. $p=1$ corresponds to Manhattan distance

Comment: @Jakub Bartczuk, I edited this now.

Comment: this sounds like homework? if so - should be marked self-study?

Comment: @seanv507 , It is not a homework!!

Comment: so what is the reason for the question?

Comment: @seanv507, very simple, after a lot of reading I came up with this question!!

Answer (score 1):

> Does the violation of this inequality affect the prediction of the KNN
>   positively or negatively?

Strictly speaking I don't think this question makes sense - how are you going to evaluate the answers, if you're not even sure of their definition (since similarity measure determines the evaluation)?

If you're asking from more technical point of view, then this can be seen as a problem. Some algorithms that are used to perform kNN, especially approximate kNN, can use triangle inequality essentially. On the other hands there are methods that can deal with similarities that don't even define metrics, or aren't symmetrical.

For example NMSLib is a library that has algorithms that can perform approximate nearest neighbor search for similarities that don't necessarily come from distances. See [NMSLib manual](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/d9d8/744fa1c527780739a843fd825b669a372a24.pdf), part 4 for more info on that.